# Symfony 2 form validate

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a simple form without a entity that I use to send emails. Now I was testing in firefox and if I leave a field empty I will get a message. But now if I open the same form in Safari (that ignores required proprty) I won't get any message. The `form->isValid()` returs true even when I leave all fields blank...

How to validate this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The in-browser validation is just a time saver to avoid a request to a server when a field is blank, but it's not a proper validation because it can be disabled on the browser level. You still should validate on the server side.

See [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html#adding-validation) — you need the `NotBlank` constraint.